# Unable to insert module using modprobe utility

Tags: kernel-module

I have tried to load a hello world kernel module using modprobe utility but I am getting the  error "FATAL: Module hello.ko not found error".

The module path is in /lib/modules/uname-r. I am able to build and create the .ko file and insert using insmod but can't do the same with modprobe.

Please clarify the difference between modprobe and insmod utility

Answer (score 0):

`modprobe` *doesn't seach* files under `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>`, but uses `modules.dep` file in this directory for map module name to file, contained that module.

For update `modules.dep` file after adding new module, use `depmod` command.

Comment: So once we update the module.dep file using depmod can we add the samemodule using modprobe in future